# C++ function inside function

Tags: c++, function

```
/*I need to use the result from the (delta) function inside the (sol_ec_II) function for a school assignment.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <ctgmath>
using namespace std;


double delta(double a, double b, double c) {
    return (b * b) - (4 * a * c);/* so I need to take this value [(b * b) - (4 * a * c)]
                               and use it in sol_ec_II in the places where I wrote "delta". */


    }
void sol_ec_II(double a, double b, double c) {
    if (delta < 0) {//here
        cout << endl << "Polinomul NU are solutii.";
    }
    else {
        double x1 = -1 * b - sqrt(delta);//here
        double x2 = -1 * b + sqrt(delta);//here

    }
}
```

// I would also need to use the (delta) function inside the (sol_ec_II) so they use the same
a, b, c values like this:

```
void sol_ec_II(double a, double b, double c) {
    delta(a, b, c);
    if (delta < 0) {
        cout << endl << "Polinomul NU are solutii.";
    }
    else {
        double x1 = -1 * b - sqrt(delta);
        double x2 = -1 * b + sqrt(delta);

    }
}
```

//so I don't understand how to get the value that results from delta(a, b, c) and use it inside the if statement and sqrt.

Comment: Assign the result to a variable: `double d = delta(a, b, c);`, then use the variable.  You can also use the function return value directly, but in your case, that would require calling `delta()` multiple times to perform the same computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result "comes out" of the function call at the time you call it. Look, you already know how `sqrt` works. `sqrt` is a function! You write `sqrt(something)` and that calls the function `sqrt` and it calls the function `sqrt` with the argument `something` and then the return value from `sqrt` gets used in the place where you wrote `sqrt(something)`. e.g. `1 + sqrt(4)` calculates 3.

Likewise the return value from `delta` gets used in the place where you wrote `delta(a, b, c)`. If you want to call delta and then call sqrt (i.e. calculate the square root of the delta) you write `sqrt(delta(a, b, c))`.

Obviously, just calculating a number is pretty useless. You probably want to do something with the number, like saving it in a variable or printing it. Examples:

```
cout << "the square root of the delta is " << sqrt(delta(a,b,c)) << endl;
cout << "the delta plus one is " << (delta(a,b,c) + 1) << endl;

double the_delta = delta(a,b,c);
cout << "the delta is " << the_delta << " and the square root of the delta is " << sqrt(the_delta) << endl;

if (delta(a,b,c) < 0)
    cout << "the delta is negative" << endl;
else
    cout << "the delta isn't negative" << endl;
```

Note: Every time the computer runs `delta(a,b,c)` it calls the `delta` function. It doesn't remember the calculation from last time. You can see this because if you put cout instructions inside the delta function, they get printed every time the computer runs `delta(a,b,c)`.

Of course I will not give you the solution for your program. I hope this helps you understand how functions work.

Answer (score 0):

here you should pass parameters to deleta function in order to execute it:

```
void sol_ec_II(double a, double b, double c) {
    if (delta(a,b,c) < 0) {//here
        cout << endl << "Polinomul NU are solutii.";
    }
    else {
        double x1 = -1 * b - sqrt(delta);//here
        double x2 = -1 * b + sqrt(delta);//here

    }
}
```

or you could save the result in a new variable called result for example, and after that use it, like that:

```
void sol_ec_II(double a, double b, double c) {
    double result = delta(a,b,c);
    if (result < 0) {//here
        cout << endl << "Polinomul NU are solutii.";
    }
    else {
        double x1 = -1 * b - sqrt(delta);//here
        double x2 = -1 * b + sqrt(delta);//here

    }
}
```

The Same thing for the second function, always to execute a function use parenthesis and pass between them the arguments that the function expects.

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the value you get from calling a function multiple time use a variable:

```
double delta(double,double,double) { return 1.2; /*ignore this for now*/ }

void sol_ec_II(double a, double b, double c) {
  const auto kDelta = delta(a, b, c);
  if (kDelta < 0.0) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    const auto kRootD = sqrt(kDelta); // same idea
    const auto x1 = -b - kRootD;
    const auto x2 = -b + kRootD;
    // use the variables
  }
}
```

I use `auto` out of habit, you don't need to, `double` is fine.